# Drag and drop, mouseenter triggered on different element

Tags: javascript, jquery

Based on some fiddle I found (do not remember which anymore, sorry), I created a "Kanban board" where I can drag and drop persons into different blocks. Its a board with tooltip/popups on the persons which is triggered on mouseenter on the person div. After completing it and starting testing, I noticed that sometimes after dropping a person I would get a new popup for a *different* person. I could not understand why and how and when. So I tried to strip my project into the fiddle below to see if I could figure out why. The fiddle is misbehaving just like my project, only here I just log the mouseenter event.

Sometimes when I take "Person A" and drag it to "Block B" and drop it the fiddle will log a hover on "Person B" afterwards. This does not happen always, though.

To me it might seem that if dragging Person A over Person B, it will trigger a mouseenter on Person B AFTER Person A is dropped. But not always. Maybe the point of drop is important. I just can't figure out exactly when it happens, but its often.

Edit: to me it seems like the mouse position remains at the point where drag starts. If I immediately after drop move mouse out of the div I'm dragging "real quick", there is a mouseenter on that previous point happening (where now a different div is).

Of course, I just want to remove any mouseenter events when I'm dragging and dropping.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="board" id="board">

    <div class="block" id="aaa" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <strong>Block A</strong>
      <div class="person" id="pa" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><span>Person A</span></div>
      <div class="person" id="pb" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><span>Person B</span></div>
      <div class="person" id="pc" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)"><span>Person C</span></div>
    </div>

    <div class="block" id="bbb" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
      <strong>Block B</strong>
    </div>

  </div>
  <textarea id="log" rows="8"></textarea>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```js
function drag(ev) {
  $("#log").val(""); //reset log on drag
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.currentTarget.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".person", function() {
    $("#log").val($("#log").val() + "\nHover on " + $(this).text());
  });
});
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/60jc17hm/

I've only tried to create a test-fiddle I can use to pinpoint when this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Hordrist answer I ended up with the below. Disable the mouseenter trigger on drag start, and then reinitialize it after mouse moves after drag ends.

```js
function displayHover(event){
  $("#log").val($("#log").val() + "\nHover on " + event.target.innerText);
}

function drag(ev) {
  $("#log").val(""); //reset log on drag
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
  $(document).off("mouseenter", ".person");
}

function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.currentTarget.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("mouseenter", ".person", displayHover);
  $(document).on("dragend", function(){
    $(document).one("mousemove", function(){
      $(document).on("mouseenter", ".person", displayHover);
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I managed to work something out.

```js
function displayHover(event){
    $("#log").val($("#log").val() + "\nHover on " + event.target.innerText);
}


$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on("mouseenter", ".person", displayHover)
  var was_dragged = false;
  $(document).on("dragend", function(){
    $(document).off("mouseenter", ".person", displayHover)
    $(document).one("mousemove", function(){
        $(document).on("mouseenter", ".person", displayHover);
    })
  });
});
```

It worked for me at least...

I will try to explain, but i'm kind of new to it myself so it will probably be terrible :

I think the thing is, when you drag an object, you have like a "new mouse" that can drag over objects but not hover them... (I guess in reality it is more technical but it is how I see it as a newbie)

So when the drag stops (Jquery dragend event), the "old" instance of the mouse (sorry for such vulgarisation) is at the old place (dragstart), hovers over the draggable element below the one you just moved (under person A is person B, at the beginning), then goes to the drop location and hovers the dropped element
So you hover Person B, then person A, after moving the Person A block

So i suggest to disable the mouseenter event when you stop a drag action, and reactivate it as soon as the mouse moves.

Comment: I tried you solution, and it actually seemed to work. I added into my complete project, but it did not work. I went back to the fiddle and tried again, and see that it is still happening with your changes. If I drop and move the cursor off the element "real quick", I still get the hover event on the old position of cursor. It's not very easy to make happen, as I do not know the cause, but I drop and move in one motion and then leave the mouse.

Comment: Oh... The problem doesn't seem to happen for me...
At one point yesterday, I modified the solution, as the first one I suggested was not functionnal (the one using "was_dragged" variable). Maybe you don't have the latest one (the one using "mousemove" event).
In other case, I'm afraid I don't see anything else, sorry...

Comment: Biggest problem is to figure out when it actually happens. 
It seems I need to use a bool, showHover. When drag STARTS I set it to false. When drag ends a mouseover will set it to true again. This seems to work best. If I use the off() instead, it seems to actually still trigger the mouseenter. So what this does it will let the mouseenter fire, but the displayHover will not do anything.  

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mjLke8of/3/

I think this is the best solution based on yours, Hordrist.

Comment: New fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/mjLke8of/4/, is very close to Hordrist answer. Just moved off() to drag start. This one seems to behave like I want it to. Although difficult to tell, will test a little more before adding or approving answer :)

Comment: I guess you can edit your answer and move the off() to drag start, and I can approve it. Or I'll add that answer myself.

Comment: @EirikR go on, you found the solution, didn't you ? ;)